# Table View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have this code `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Why doesn't the table view deselect the row, What am i doing wrong.

EDIT:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)path {
//------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
// huh?
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES];
}
```

The `…didDeselect…` method is called only when the cell is *already* deselected. But you want to deselect that cell only after it's already deselected... sounds strange? Perhaps you mean  `…didSelect…`?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)path {
//------------------------------------------^^^^^^
// yay.
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: oh thnx, my bad, was looking fot didSelect... Typo!

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

1. Use `NSLog` to troubleshoot the value of `indexPath`
2. Make sure your `tableView` is wired up to the view controller in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to stop your users from being able to select a row in your table view, this is the code you need:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
```